# PHP Command With Variable In CRON Job Always Failed

Tags: php, cron

I have this cron job inside my cpanel :

```
php /home/myusername/public_html/cron/cron.cancel-order.php 9304920492304
```

and here's `cron.cancel-order.php` looks like :

```
if (isset($argv[1])) {
    if ($argv[1] == $cron_key) {
            echo 'you are here 1';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'you are here 2';
    }
} else {
    echo 'you are here 3';
}
```

why I always got `you are here 3` as result of the CRON job. in fact, I tried to run the same command from SSH, I can get `you are here 1`.

does running PHP from CRON requires some another argument? or options? thank you.

Comment: Try changing `php-cli ....` instead of `php ...`

Comment: where does `$cron_key` come from?

Comment: I think adding `-f` can make it work: `php -f /home/...`.